# Magento1.9.1 Spam newsletter subscriptions

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, newsletter

How to block spam newsletter subscription?

I have added captcha and form key for newsletter subscription but still get spam subscription.

These subscriptions have unsubscribed status.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a reCaptcha to avoid spam (I recommend invisible reCaptcha v2)

Answer (score 0):

1.Enable the newsletter email confirmation setting from Magento 1 admin as,
  System >> Configuration >> Customer >> Newsletter >> Need to confirm : Yes

2.And as Jake mentioned you need to install the google Invisible recaptcha plugin. you may check below from Amasty,
https://amasty.com/magento-google-invisible-captcha.html